# How to check UICollectionView has image

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

I have 4 UICollectionViewCell in which I want to make first 2 cell to have image in it mandatory. Sample code is as below. Below is a usecase:

There are 4 UICollectionViewCell if I click on each cell will open camera and we can either take a photo or select image from image gallery. How to know first 2 cell must have image. Looking for condition to check this logic.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Image *image = (Image *)self.defect.imageSet[indexPath.item];
    ADRPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ADRPhotoCollectionViewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.image = image.thumbnailImage ? image.thumbnailImage : nil;
    cell.photoType = [self.defect defectPhotoTypeForIndex:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   Image *image = self.defect.imageSet[indexPath.item];

    if (self.selectedImage != image) {

       [self updateAnnotatedImage];
        self.selectedImage = image;
       [self.jotController clearAll];
       [self updateUserInterface];

    if (image.thumbnailImage) {
        [self transitionImage:YES];
    } else {
        self.imageView.image = nil;
        [self showCameraPicker];
    }

} else if (!image.thumbnailImage) {
      //clicked the + to add a new image
      [self showCameraPicker];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "How to know first 2 cell must have image " ? DO you mean, you want to check if the first 2 cells already have image or not ?

Comment: Yes I want to check cellForItemAtIndexPath 0 and 1 has image.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is an image in `UIImageView` or not by this way:

```
-(BOOL) checkImages {
    for (int i=0, i<2 , i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        ADRPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.imageView.image == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(cell.imageView.image.size, CGSizeZero)) {
            //there isn't any image or the image is empty
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Still no. I want to check cellForItemAtIndexPath 0 and 1 has image.

Comment: This will not have collectionView object outside delegate method

Comment: you can set outlet for your collectionView and access to it every where you want in your class

Comment: Now it always returning 1.

Comment: even when imageView has an image ?

Comment: Yes on both case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189760/discussion-between-nagarjun-and-arash-etemad).